# Android Activity causing app to crash, but it is not being called at any point as far as I can see

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, logcat, extends

In the class OilPlots I have the following method, which should load the Activity BoPlots:

```
OnClickListener OilList = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(OilPlots.this, BoPlots.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    };
```

Below is the onCreate() method for BoPlots:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bo_plots);

        setup();        
        color(button4, R.id.buttonLayout ,R.id.button4);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bo);
        btn.setOnClickListener(BoList);

    }
```

The first time I load the Activity BoPlots it loads fine, but if I try and access it from the OilPlots class it crashes the app. The logcat is below:

```
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.resengin/com.example.resengin.BoPlots}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:337)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at com.example.resengin.BoResults.onCreate(BoResults.java:74)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at com.example.resengin.BoPlots.onCreate(BoPlots.java:20)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    ... 11 more
```

from what I can understand, the crash is being caused by:

```
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 22:06:15.649: E/AndroidRuntime(32339):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
```

which is causing a crash because the variable has not been instantiated. 
The line of code this seems to be referring to is in the Activity BoResults. the onCreate method for this Activity is below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bo_results);

        setup();        
        color(button3, R.id.buttonLayout ,R.id.button3);

        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.results).findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.results).findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.results).findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        Intent intent = getIntent();        

        Float Pressure = Float.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("V1"));
        Float Temp = Float.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("V2"));
        Float STOG = Float.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("V3"));
        Float SG = Float.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("V4"));
        Float SGOR = Float.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("V5"));


        txt1.setText(String.valueOf(Pressure));
        txt2.setText(String.valueOf(Temp));
        txt3.setText(String.valueOf(STOG));   

        spreadsheet();

    }
```

But I don't understand why this is being called, as there is no point in the code referring to anything in the BoResults Activity, or calling any methods. The BoPlots does extend BoResults

Comment: I think we're going to need a little bit more info. What do setup() and spreadsheet() look like? My guess is that there's something happening in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So BoPlots extends BoResults? In your BoPlots onCreate method you're calling super.onCreate which will call the BoResults version. So if you didn't add the same extras to your BoPlots intent that BoResults needs, it will crash. Sounds like you shouldn't be extending BoResults.

Answer (score 0):

`getStringExtra` returns `null` if  a mapped value for the key does not exist. If you try to convert `null` to `float` the application will cras